# atemporal means not relate to specific time; is there a word for "not related to specific place"?

Tags: vocabulary

I can write "the story is atemporal" as a specific "time" (as in setting) can not be established from the context; there must be a word that means 'not specific location" -as in setting also but meaning 'not located place'... do you know such word? Thanks!

Comment: "Nowhere", "in no particular location", "anywhere", "nowhere in particular" come to mind but no "atemporal"-type word.

Comment: [Related](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/112002).

Answer (score 1):

In terms of ["derivational morphology"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_(linguistics)), the closest match to OP's ***atemporal*** is probably [***aspatial***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22aspatial%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) - which as the link shows is certainly in use. But per John's comment below, when applied to things like a *story, narrative*, ***alocale*** is more commonly used.

But I might go for a slightly more "accessible" form, such as [***non-locational***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22aspatial%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22non-locational%22&tbm=bks) - but again, note John's comment that [***non-locative***](http://ling.auf.net/lingbuzz/000914) has a specific sense in grammar/linguistics.

Comment: _Non-locative_, for grammatical purposes. And _alocal_ is the analog of _atemporal_.

Comment: @John: Ah, right. I thought *non-locative* sounded more like a linguistic/grammar sort of term. And I only said *aspatial* because  *temporal/spatial coordinates* often occur together.

Comment: But they used to shout 'Time!' at the local.